# print a defined variable with preserving $

Tags: shell, printing

I would like to print 120 model list along with preserving the "$".

My script is:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in {1..10};do
declare model="$"model$i
model_list=$(paste $model)
done
echo $model_list
```

After running it,

```
paste: $model1: No such file or directory
paste: $model2: No such file or directory
paste: $model3: No such file or directory
paste: $model4: No such file or directory
paste: $model5: No such file or directory
paste: $model6: No such file or directory
paste: $model7: No such file or directory
paste: $model8: No such file or directory
paste: $model9: No such file or directory
paste: $model10: No such file or directory
```

Desired output:

```
$model1 $model2 $model3 $model4 $model5 $model6 $model7 $model8 $model9 $model10
```

Comment: Do you know what the `paste` command does? Or what command substitution (`$(...)`) is? Does the file `./$model1` solely contain the text `$model1`? If not then your script and understanding of the commands are faulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are interested in output instead of creating array the you can use below code

```
for i in {1..10};do
echo -n "\$model$i "
done
echo
```

or

```
for i in {1..10};do
echo -n '$model'$i' '
done
echo
```

or

```
for i in {1..10};do
model_list=$model_list" \$model$i"
done
echo $model_list
```

Comment: Actually the model_list has been defined in another command. So I need exactly like what I have asked. Would you please suggest to do that?

Comment: try 3rd option I have added in my answer. let me know if it works

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the `$` via `\$` (backslash dollar-sign).

For instance:

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in {1..10}; do
  declare model="\$"model$i

  model_list+=$(paste $model)
done
echo $model_list
```

You can also shorten your script:

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in {1..10}; do
  model_list+=$(paste "\$model${i}")
done

echo $model_list
```

Tested with 5 files titled `$model1 - $model5`:

```
File Contents:
$model1 - a b c d e f g
$model2 - 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
$model3 - I J K L M N O P
$model4 - 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
$model5 - q r s t u v w x y z

Output:
a b c d e f g1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10I J K L M N O P11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20q r s t u v w x y z
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am still getting same error.

Comment: @Kayan Oh you need to change `=` to `+=`, I'll update my answer.